# Nhibernate HiLo generator is generating duplicate ids

Tags: c#, sqlite, nhibernate

I am facing weird behavior of nHibernate. It does generate duplicate Ids with hi-lo generator in some circumstances. 
If the transaction is rolled back, and the number of id's to generate is more than hi-lo max, eventually it starts to generate the duplicates - Debug.Assert fails.

Maybe someone had faced something like that, or just knows how to prevent this ? Database is sqlite if it matters.

```
private void Test(ISessionFactory factory)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            using (var session = factory.OpenSession())
            using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                CheckIdGenerator(session.GetSessionImplementation(), 11);
                transaction.Rollback();
            }
        }
    }

private void CheckIdGenerator(ISessionImplementor sessionImplementor, int max)
{
    var factory = sessionImplementor.Factory;
    var mapping= (SingleTableEntityPersister)factory.GetClassMetadata(typeof(Dummy));
    var generator= mapping.IdentifierGenerator;

    var ids = new List<long>();
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
    {
        var id = (long)generator.Generate(sessionImplementor, null);
        Debug.Assert(!ids.Contains(id));
        ids.Add(id);
    }
}
```

mapping:

```
class DummyMap : ClassMap<Dummy>
      {
            public DummyMap()
            {
                Id(x => x.Id)
                    .UniqueKey(nameof(Dummy.Id))
                    .GeneratedBy.HiLo("NHHiLoIdentity", "NextHiValue", "10",
                        $"[EntityName] = '[{nameof(Dummy)}]'")
                    .Not.Nullable();
            }
        }
```

Comment: I never had this problem. NHibernate tries to get the id in a different transaction and i suspect it gets no different but the same transaction which is rolled back.

Comment: I am getting Debug.Assert failure in 100% cases on 3rd cycle run (i=2)

Comment: @Firo you can write your comment as an answer. You are correct. It's the same transaction, which is rolled back.

Comment: @xll Did you actually have any similar problem during normal use of NHibernate? Because the code you show is poking around in the internals.

Comment: @OskarBerggren The same happens if I call session.Save. The problem is quite simple actually. Sqlite allows only one connection that can write. So the update from Id generator runs  in the same connection and even in the same transaction. But the transaction is rolled back, so all updates are lost. Eventually Id generator will read reads DB to get NextHiValue, and will read old one that existed before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NHibernate tries to get the id in a different transaction and Sqlite only allows one connection which already has a transaction. This transactionis rolled back so the hi value will be the same between reads.